# can't read pdf stream using angularjs $resource

Tags: angularjs, pdf, download, stream, pdfkit

Can't figure it out... what am I doing wrong?

I get the following pdf stream from the server (it seems I'm receiving an string array with %PDF...) using $resource

```
data[0] = %
data[1] = P
data[2] = D
data[3] = F
...
```

I can't manage to generate the pdf file from this stream. This is the code I'm using...

```
vm.downloadCertificate = function () {
  var pdfCertificateService = new PDFCertificatesService()
  pdfCertificateService.$get({
    certificateId: vm.certificate._id
  }).then(function (data) {

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:application/pdf,' + encodeURI(data);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
    hiddenElement.click();
  })
}
```

Please some help! None of the other posts have been helpfulso far.

Comment: Add your code and error in the question (not as images).

Comment: Thanks, first post... I tried to create a BLOB out of the steam but as expected it didn't work. I'm receiving an array of strings for the streammed pdf.

Comment: if i do something like var string = data.toString('base64') I get an '[object Object]' string...